# sql LIKE statement combined from three "like"`s

Tags: sql, select, sql-like

how to combine sql query from three like statements? I`m trying like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE 
  (NAME LIKE '%someChars%' AND 
    (CITY LIKE '%someChars%' AND 
     TYPE LIKE'% someChars%')
  );
```

It doesn`t work, can you help me with that please ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I really think the parenthesis are unnecessary, despite I haven't tested.

Comment: As Math said, the parenthesis are unecessary and may even be the sourceo of your problem

Answer (score 1):

The query is correct except the fact that `Type` is a sql keyword, so try putting it between bracket like that:

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable] 
 WHERE ([NAME] LIKE '%someChars%' AND
        ([CITY] LIKE '%someChars%' AND
         [TYPE] LIKE '%someChars%'));
```

PS: The parenthesis are not needed

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE
  NAME LIKE '%someChars%' AND
  CITY LIKE '%someChars%' AND
  TYPE LIKE '%someChars%';
```